# Spring MVC model binding not working for non public members

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have class `Product` with members like `Name`, `Description`... which are private, and I have public getter and setter methods. I tried to make `Spring Boot MVC REST` controller with `POST` method but it seams that what I am sending is not bind to model. This is JSON I'm sending to controller:

```
{
    "Name": "proizvod7",
    "Description": "neki opis2",
    "CategoryId":1,
    "Price":"15"
}
```

This is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"","/"},method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json",produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity PostProduct(@RequestBody @Valid Product p, BindingResult result){

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.insert(p), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } else
        return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

I figured that out when I created new class `ProductDto` which has public members `Name`, `Description`...

This is working version:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"","/"},method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json",produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity PostProduct(@RequestBody @Valid ProductDto productDto, BindingResult result) {

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        Product p = new Product(productDto.Name, productDto.Price, productDto.Description, productDto.CategoryId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.insert(p), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } else {
        return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

However project is simple enough so I don't want to introduce `DTO` classes, but I would like to have private members inside my initial `Product` class with public getters and setters. Is it possible?

EDIT:
Here is `Product` class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "products")
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    public Product(@NotNull String name, BigDecimal price, String description, Long category_id) {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Description = description;
        Category_id = category_id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return Price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        Price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    @NotNull
    private String Name;

    private BigDecimal Price;

    private String Description;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Long getCategory_id() {
        return Category_id;
    }

    public void setCategory_id(Long category_id) {
        Category_id = category_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "category_id",nullable = true)
    private Long Category_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Category category;

}
```

Comment: are you sure in your DTO Product  fields are spelled correctly ? I mean field named Description and description are different according to json deserializer

Comment: Yes, my Product and ProductDto classes have Name, Description properties with  capital letter N and D. I will add Product class later when on PC but it is simple class with private fields, public getters ans setters and few anottations like @Entity

Comment: @kiranMohan it is important if I send description or Description in JSON? Every minute I found reason for ASP.NET MVC agains this Spring MVC stuff :)

Comment: *I would like to have private members inside my initial Product class with public getters and setters. Is it possible*. So add your Product class to the question.

Comment: @AlanHay ok, here is my Product class in edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your field names are breaking the deserializing logic. I do not know why are you trying to use those uppercase field names, but the problem is that when there is a setter for `Name` field, `setName()`, Jackson thinks this maps to a field `name`, not `Name`, hence the issue.

You should use `@JsonProperty()`

```
@JsonProperty("Name")
private String Name;

@JsonProperty("Price")
private BigDecimal Price;

@JsonProperty("Description")
private String Description;

@JsonProperty("categoryId")
@Column(name = "category_id", nullable = true)
private Long Category_id;
```

Also with `@Data` annotation from Lombok, you do not need to write all those getters/setters, they are already generated for you.

Comment: ...and change the Java field names to be consistent with standard naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonSetter at the public setters... something like this

```
public class MyBean {
    private String name;

    @JsonSetter("name")
    public void setTheName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You can check more examples here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

`@JsonSetter` ref here https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html